# How to remove Axis project facets from WebProject in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, apache-axis

I have a web project in eclipse, I used axis for some operation but then I changed my mind.
Now if I go to Project->Project Facets and try to unselect "Axis2 web service" it tells me that cannot be uninstalled.

How can I uninstall it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way would be to restore an old version from version control. Or you could at least look into version control to see what adding the facet changed.

If you don't have version control, right now would be a good time to start with it. Because if you have to remove the facet manually, chances are that you'll break something.

To remove the facet manually, look into the file `.classpath` and `.project` and remove anything that remotely looks like it's related to Axis. Then delete the project from the workspace (only the project, not the *content*) and import it again. Afterwards, chances are that the Axis nature is gone.

If you made a mistake during this process, you can use version control to undo it.

Answer (score 1):

this may help you
[Eclipse irreversible Dynamic Web Module 4.0 selection; Tomcat 9 doesn't support it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649041/eclipse-irreversible-dynamic-web-module-4-0-selection-tomcat-9-doesnt-support)

> Edit the file org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml in the
> project's .settings directory.