# Can't set Dynamic Web Project version to 4.0 in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

With `Eclipse EE 4.7.3`, `Java 1.8.0_161` and `Apache Tomcat 9.0.6` I cannot create Dynamic Web Project 4.0, the maximum available version is 3.1:

[image: Eclipse: create Dynamic Web project]

I also can't change version to 4.0 in Project Facets, the maximum version is again 3.1:

[image: Eclipse: project facets]

How do I set Dynamic Web Module version to 4.0?

Comment: Possible duplicate of _Eclipse irreversible Dynamic Web Module 4.0 selection; Tomcat 9 doesn't support it_ . See
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48649041/eclipse-irreversible-dynamic-web-module-4-0-selection-tomcat-9-doesnt-support/48657610#48657610. The workaround is to edit your project's **core.xml** file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right Click on your project folder.
2. Go to Show In > Navigator
3. Go to Navigator and expand the .settings folder
4. Open org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml file

   ```
   <faceted-project>
     <fixed facet="wst.jsdt.web"/>
     <installed facet="jst.web" version="3.1"/>
     <installed facet="wst.jsdt.web" version="1.0"/>
     <installed facet="java"`enter code here` version="1.8"/>
   </faceted-project>
   ```
5. Change the version like this  `<installed facet="jst.web" version="4.0"/>`
6. Save
7. Just update your project. Right Click on The Project Folder > Maven > Update Project
8. Select the Project and click 'Ok'
   Works like a charm.